# classic asp getting value of global variable

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to just output the global.asa Application("SiteURL"), but I get nothing
showing for SiteURL.  I have it defined in the global.asa as

```
    <!--METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" FILE="c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" -->

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript"  RUNAT="Server">
       Sub Application_OnStart
          Application("SiteURL") = "http://[localhost]/asp3test/" 
          Application("myAppVariable") = "Apple" 
          Application("CurrentDateTime") = ""  
       End Sub
   </SCRIPT>
```

This is my test.asp file:

```
 <BODY>
 Let's retrieve the values of the Application Variables:<P>
 myAppVariable = <%= Application("myAppVariable")%><BR>
 SiteURL = <%= Application("SiteURL")%> <br />
 CurrentDateTime = <%= Application("CurrentDateTime")%><br />

 Now, let's set the variables:<HR>
 <%
 Application.Lock
 Application("CurrentDateTime") = Now
 Application.UnLock
 %>
 Variables set - <A HREF="test.asp">click here</A> to reload the page to view
 </BODY>
```

Result:

```
Let's retrieve the values of the Application Variables:

myAppVariable =
SiteURL =
CurrentDateTime = 12/22/2013 1:47:42 PM
Now, let's set the variables:
```

The values that are set in the Global.asa file do not seem to be grabbed, like it
is not being read (processed), but when I manually set the values to a Application(variable), it seems to hold it.  So something missing with with Global.asa is not being read.  I am on IIS 7.5.76 and Win7(64bit), not sure if that helps.

Comment: I've removed the ASP.NET tag.  ASP.NET and Classic ASP are **not** the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got it inside the correct `Sub` within your `global.asa`? i.e.

```
Sub Application_OnStart
    Application("SiteURL") = "http://[localhost]/asp3test/"
End Sub
```

Comment: I added some additional info.  But yes, they are in the global.asa

Comment: And `test.asp` is in the root of the virtual server?

Comment: I read somewhere that I need to change the name of the Application Directory on IIS?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427779/classic-asp-asp-net-website-global-asa-not-working

Comment: If `test.asp` is in a directory with its own application then it cannot access the variables of the root application.

Comment: There is no folder.  All files are on the same root for this website.  I wonder if I have configured it correctly?

Comment: @user1929393 try causing error in `global.asa` on purpose e.g. remove `End Sub` line. If you don't get any error when viewing the .asp page it means the `global.asa` file is not being called, better ask new question in that case. If you do get error it means problem with the code itself and we'll debug it further.

Answer (score 0):

My website was not setup correctly...  I had to add application to the default website for it to work.  The reason it did not work before is because I created just a website separate from the default website, and did not ADD Application to that website.  However, I was getting an error trying to create add application in IIS.  I heard somewhere this is a bug.  That tripped me up.